# Retrieving updated files from server to replace files on documents folder of an iPhone

Tags: iphone, documents

Im new to iPhone programming and wanted to see how people have solved this problem:

Ive created my app which will ship with certain pLists and .png files in the main bundle. However, what I want to do is when the app starts up, Id like it to check my server to see if there are updated versions of the files in the documents folder available. If so Id like the app to download those files.

I was wondering if someone can point me to some resources on how to do this? Ive searched online but haven't come up with good hits.

Whats the google key-word for searching this topic anyways?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use NSUrlRequest to download the files, to move them to the correct place you can use NSFileManager, if you look at the apple docs for both these classes there should be sample code explaining how to copy/save a file from NSData, and also how to download it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any example resources of how to do exactly this, though I would probably do something along the lines of onAppLoad checking to see if the content of the application that you want to keep updated is the most recent, and if not, download it.

As for keywords to search I would try something along the lines of "Automatic App Content Updating/Verification" and throw in "iOS/iPhone/iPad" or some similar combination.

I'll do some more poking around and shoot you a comment notification if I find anything worthwhile, and then edit my post with it.